# How can I intercept MIDI messages?

Tags: java, midi

I'm writing an application to control Novation's launchpad devices (for those familiar). The launchpad installs two MIDI devices : one for input (buttons pressed), and one for output (control LEDs).

The idea is that upon receiving a message from the launchpad, I want to send a sequence of other messages. What's the best way to do that ?

For now, I chain the input device's Transmitter to the output device's Receiver, so that every message received is directly sent back to the launchpad :

```
Transmitter lpTransmitter = inputDevice.getTransmitter();
lpTransmitter.setReceiver(outputDevice.getReceiver());
```

Comment: "upon receiving a message from the launchpad, send a sequence of other messages." You have correctly described how it works. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Well, how do I know that I have received a message ? Is there some kind of event listener ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the solution myself. What I did is I chained the devices using my own implementation of Transmitter and Receiver. As I understand it, the midi message goes like this :

launchpad input -> inputDevice's receiver -> inputDevice's transmitter -> my own receiver -> (my computations) -> my own transmitter -> outputDevice's receiver -> outputDevice's transmitter -> launchpad output.

Now bear with me, because I don't know if this is **the proper way** to do it, but my code goes like this :

```
// main
// get launchpad devices, open them

MyMidiDevice myDevice = new MyMidiDevice();

inputDevice.getTransmitter().setReceiver(myDevice);
myDevice.setReceiver(outputDevice.getReceiver());
```

Code of the MyMidiDevice class :

```
public class MyMidiDevice implements Transmitter, Receiver
{

    private Receiver receiver;

    @Override
    public Receiver getReceiver()
    {
        return this.receiver;
    }

    @Override
    public void setReceiver(Receiver receiver)
    {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    @Override
    public void close()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void send(MidiMessage message, long timeStamp)
    {
        System.out.println(message); // computations
        this.getReceiver().send(message, timeStamp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `javax.sound.midi` package has an interface that is implemented by code that wants to receive events. It is called [Receiver](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/Receiver.html).

Take care to [open the device before getting the transmitter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6937760/11654).

Comment: I know about Receiver, but how do I use it to receive messages ? Do I create my own class that implements it ? The javadoc tells me I have to define `send()`, but will that method be automatically called if I link a transmitter ? Pardon the ignorance, I'm a beginner in Java