# Java MIDI: Connecting MIDI Keyboard to Default Synthesizer

Tags: java, input, keyboard, midi

I gotta a MIDI Keyboard. 
All I want is an example of how I can setup the default software synthesizer to play sounds as I play the Keyboard.

```
package cleffsgame;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiDevice;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiUnavailableException;

public class CheckDevices {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MidiDevice device;
        // display each device's properties
        for (MidiDevice.Info info: MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo()) {

            try {
                device = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(info);

                System.out.println("\nDevice: ");
                System.out.println("Name: " + device.getDeviceInfo().getName());
                System.out.println("Vendor: " + device.getDeviceInfo().getVendor());
                System.out.println("Version: " + device.getDeviceInfo().getVersion());
                System.out.println("Description: " + device.getDeviceInfo().getDescription());
                System.out.println("Transmitters: " + device.getMaxTransmitters());
                System.out.println("Receivers: " + device.getMaxReceivers());

            } catch (MidiUnavailableException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(CheckDevices.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By running the code above, I get the following output:

> run:
>
> Device:  Name: Gervill Vendor: OpenJDK Version: 1.0 Description:
>   Software MIDI Synthesizer Transmitters: 0 Receivers: -1
>
> Device:  Name: Oxygen 49 Vendor: M-Audio Version: Unknown version
>   Description: Oxygen 49 Transmitters: -1 Receivers: 0
>
> Device:  Name: Oxygen 49 Vendor: M-Audio Version: Unknown version
>   Description: Oxygen 49 Transmitters: 0 Receivers: -1
>
> Device:  Name: Real Time Sequencer Vendor: Oracle Corporation Version:
>   Version 1.0 Description: Software sequencer Transmitters: -1
>   Receivers: -1 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)

But when I run the code below, no sound is played when I hit the keys.

```
package cleffsgame;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiDevice;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.midi.Receiver;
import javax.sound.midi.Synthesizer;
import javax.sound.midi.Transmitter;

/**
 *
 * @author umberto
 */
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MidiDevice inputDevice = null, synthDevice = null;
        Transmitter transmitter = null;
        Synthesizer synthesizer = null;
        Receiver receiver = null;

        try {
            inputDevice = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo()[1]);
            synthDevice = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo()[0]);

        } catch (MidiUnavailableException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        // goodDevice must be Oxygen 49 transmitter (MIDI Input)
        if (inputDevice != null && synthDevice != null) {
            try {
                transmitter = inputDevice.getTransmitter();
                System.out.println("Transmitter: " + inputDevice.getDeviceInfo());
                System.out.println(String.format("T/R: %s/%s", inputDevice.getMaxTransmitters(), inputDevice.getMaxReceivers()));

                receiver = synthDevice.getReceiver();
                System.out.println("Receiver: " + synthDevice.getDeviceInfo());
                System.out.println(String.format("T/R: %s/%s", synthDevice.getMaxTransmitters(), synthDevice.getMaxReceivers()));

                transmitter.setReceiver(receiver);
                System.out.println("GoodDevice is open... check sound\n");
                inputDevice.open();
                synthDevice.open();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

    }


}
```

It seems there is more to do than connecting a Synthesizer.receiver to a InputDevice.transmitter as I got from the docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/MIDI-synth.html.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to assign a patch instrument to the Synthesizer?

Comment: @Ishmael if you can, please check the code below. I openned the kb device and the synth before manipulating them. I loaded an instrument too, but yet no sound at all.
If you can write some hello world snnipet, it would realy help, since I never worked with midi before.

Comment: Do [these examples](http://www.jsresources.org/examples/) work?

Comment: I saw them but I didn't download since only MidiDump.java was supposed to catch input from my Keyboard and send it to the Console instead of a Synth. I tried this one and it confirmed my keyboard is correctly sending MidiEvents to the system. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937760/java-getting-input-from-midi-keyboard.

Comment: @Ishmael In my experience, it didn't require any setup of the internal synth's patches.  Channel 1 was a piano.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
transmitter.setReceiver(new Receiver() {
    @Override
    public void send(MidiMessage message, long timeStamp) {
        receiver.send(message, -1);
    }
    @Override
    public void close() {
        receiver.close();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good idea to open the devices before acquiring their transmitter/receiver.

But the actual problem is that this program exits immediately, so the devices aren't open for a useful amount of time.

Comment: Do you think the code below will work?
`
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Synthesizer s = MS.getSynthesizer();
        s.open();
        Instrument[] inst = s.getAvailableInstruments();
        s.loadInstrument(inst[0]);
        Receiver r = s.getReceiver();
        
        MidiDevice kb =         MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo()[1]);
        kb.open();
        Transmitter t = kb.getTransmitter();
        t.setReceiver(r);
        
        // keep alive..
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.add(...);
        }
`

Comment: Sorry about the unformatted code above.
Anyway, I tried openning the midi keyboard and the synth before calling other methods on them and yet I had no sound at all.
My keyboard works just fine in other apps like Logic Pro and Virtual Midi Piano Kb.
I need some Hello World code on getting sound from MIDI Keyboard.

Comment: Well, does your program stay open?

Comment: Yes, it does. Do you have a MIDI Keyboard to test if that code works on your machine @cl?

Comment: In my experiments, I didn't need to open MIDI devices before configuring them.  I configured them first, then opened them afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Recently tried to do the same thing.  Java tutorials and Stackoverflow answers weren't working.  The problem was that, I was passing the keyboard's Note On `timestamp` to the internal synth.  The fix was to pass `-1` as the timestamp instead.

This example uses Kotlin to call the Java MIDI APIs.

JDK 17, MacOS 11.3, Kotlin 1.6

```
import javax.sound.midi.*

class ReceiverAdapter (val targetReceiver: Receiver) : Receiver {

    override fun send(midiMsg: MidiMessage, timeStamp: Long) {
        targetReceiver.send(midiMsg, -1); // only works for me when i pass -1 as timestamp instead of original value from keyboard
    }
    override fun close() {  }
}

class MidiKeyboardInternalSynthExample {

    companion object {

        fun doIt(keyboardDeviceName: String){

            // connect external keyboard to internal synth
            val midiTransmitter = find1stMidiTransmitterWithName(keyboardDeviceName)
            if(midiTransmitter != null) {
                val synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer()!!
                val midiReceiver = ReceiverAdapter(synth.receiver)
                midiTransmitter.transmitter.receiver = midiReceiver
                synth.open()
                midiTransmitter.open()
            }
            else {
                println("Didn't find MIDI transmitter named '$keyboardDeviceName'.")
            }
        }

        fun find1stMidiTransmitterWithName(deviceName: String): MidiDevice? =
            MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo()
                ?.filter { info -> info.name == deviceName }
                ?.map { info -> MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(info) }
                ?.filter { device -> device.maxTransmitters == -1 }
                ?.first()
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    MidiKeyboardInternalSynthExample.doIt("LPK25")
}
```