# Recording multiple MIDI tracks

Tags: java, midi, javasound

I am writing an application that records MIDI data from a keyboard.

It should be able to record multiple tracks and store them in one MIDI file. 
It is controlled with three buttons - "record", "stop recording" and "write to a MIDI file".

I followed [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485307/java-midi-getting-data-from-piano.com) on StackOverflow to write the recording method.

Everything was going well until I tried to record a second track. track#2 is recorded, but it is placed in the sequence *behind* the track#1 i.e. they don´t play simultaneously in the  MIDI file and if I try to play only track#2, there is a lot of blank space in the beginning of it.

I read that I have to use

```
Sequencer.setTickPosition(0);
```

which I did, but without any effect.

Here are parts of the code:

The user presses "record" button:

```
  sequencer.open();   
  sequencer.setSequence(mySequence);     

  newTrack = mySequence.createTrack();
  sequencer.setTickPosition(0);    

  sequencer.recordEnable(newTrack, -1);
  sequencer.startRecording();
```

When "stop recording" button is pressed:

```
  sequencer.stopRecording();            
  sequencer.recordDisable(newTrack);
```

And finally when "write to MIDI file" button is pressed:

```
   Sequence tmp = sequencer.getSequence();
   MidiSystem.write(tmp, 1, new File("Sequence.MID"));
```

//*******************************************************************

Here is my full code:

```
  private MidiDevice inputDevice // Selected from a combo box

  private Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
  private Transmitter transmitter = inputDevice.getTransmitter();
  private Receiver receiver = sequencer.getReceiver();
  transmitter.setReceiver(receiver);
  private Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ,24);
  private Track newTrack;
   /*
  . 
  Buttons added
  .
  */

 public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
    Object source = e.getSource();

    if (source == record){

      sequencer.open();   
      sequencer.setSequence(seq);   

      newTrack = seq.createTrack();
      sequencer.setTickPosition(0);        
      sequencer.recordEnable(newTrack, -1);
      sequencer.startRecording();

      }       

//*********************************************************************  
    if (source == stop){
        sequencer.stopRecording();             
        sequencer.recordDisable(newTrack);
    }
//******************************************************************
  if(source == write){        
    Sequence tmp = sequencer.getSequence();

    MidiSystem.write(tmp, 1, new File("MyMidiFile1.mid"));  

  }
```

}

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: can you show full code with the second track created?