# Read live MIDI data from a piano and output to console?

Tags: java, live, midi

I want to create a program that will take the notes that I play on my midi enabled piano which is connected to my computer via a scarlet 2i4, and display the notes in the console as I play.  I have read the Java documentation for the MIDI part, but I am very confused where the data goes, and how I can display it.  This is what I have written so far:

```
    public class Get {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MidiUnavailableException{
        javax.sound.midi.MidiDevice.Info[] infos = MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo();
        System.out.println("Select Midi Device Number:");
        for(int i=0;i<infos.length;i++){
            System.out.println("Device Number " + i + ": " + infos[i].getName() + " - " + infos[i].getDescription());
        }
        System.out.println("Enter device number then press enter...");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int deviceNumber = in.nextInt();
        MidiDevice inputDevice = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(infos[deviceNumber]);
        inputDevice.open();
        Transmitter trans = inputDevice.getTransmitter();
        System.out.println(trans.toString());

    }

}
```

Comment: Well... What is outputted?  Are you encountering an exception? Don't expect us to run your code to determine these things

Comment: It doesn't do much at this point besides open the proper midi device I believe.  I am mainly seeking advice on how midi data is transmitted in the Java language.  Like would I try to make a loop that keeps reading the midi device continually?  Any advice on the approach would be extremely helpful

Comment: That is why I'm asking.  Your last line is a `System.out::println` and I'm wondering what it prints

Comment: Oh sure! Yes, so the output is as follows:  Exception in thread "main" javax.sound.midi.MidiUnavailableException: MIDI OUT transmitter not available
 at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractMidiDevice.createTransmitter(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractMidiDevice.getTransmitter(Unknown Source)
 at Get.main(Get.java:23)

Comment: If you are using an IDE, can you tell me what code is on line 23?  I'm assuming what you have posted above is not the full file as it is missing the `package` declaration.

Comment: Yes, it is the line: Transmitter trans = inputDevice.getTransmitter();      I am assuming that this means that Java will get the transmitter from my respective midi device which should be the information coming in from that device

Comment: Oh.. I don't know why I didn't see this before.  I believe the `Transmitter` is used to transmit data **back** to the MIDI device not receive data from.

Comment: Check this post out, it may be able to help you more than I can:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485307/java-midi-getting-data-from-piano?rq=1

Comment: Oh okay.  So Should I be using inputDevice.getReciever();?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java MIDI - getting data from piano?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485307/java-midi-getting-data-from-piano)

Comment: No, the input device's transmitter sends to your own receiver.

Comment: Would I create a loop with the receiver outputting the data it receiver from the transmitter connected to my midi device?  And what is your suggestion for displaying the midi note information?